# Installing ubuntu from USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, bios

I want to change my OS from windows to UBUNTU. So what I did is below.

I downloaded the `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` from [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) saved it in a usb and set the boot order of USB to be the first boot in BIOS. But the installation failed.

What causes the installation to fail? after saving the changes in BIOS the laptop restarts and goes to windows

Additional information

Laptop is new and i am installing to change os to practice programming better.

Comment: I am using usb.. also i tried those steps

Comment: That covers usb and you clearly missed a step, don't just put the iso on the usb, use the tools mentioned to create the usb.

Comment: You mean burn in usb? Is that not same sa saving in usb?

Comment: You need to use a program like this https://rufus.akeo.ie/ to write to the usb and make it bootable, just putting the file on there won't work.

Comment: @MarkKirby i made the usb bootable i disabled secure boot still it wont boot from usb

Comment: What program did you use to make the USB stick and what computer are we talking about, make/model?